My function returns the observable only once
I have the following service:
// transloco-loader.ts

import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {TranslocoLoader } from '@ngneat/transloco';
import { map, take} from 'rxjs';
import { CFV2 } from '@go/shared-data-access-angular-config';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TranslocoHttpLoader implements TranslocoLoader {
  private _configFacade = inject(CFV2.ConfigFacade);
  
  getTranslation(lang: string) {

    // We always get here
    console.log('function gets called each time');

    return this._configFacade.configState$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((state) => {

        // But not here! Although configState$ didn't change!
        console.log('But we get here ONLY ONCE!');

        return { t: 'something' };
      }),
    );
  }
}


If I call getTranslation method 2 times, only the first time it goes into the pipe! Am I missing something here? I'm using Angular 17.
I could actually manage to fix the issue by using the async syntax:
async getTranslation(lang: string): Promise<{ t: string }> {
    console.log('function gets called each time');

    const state = await firstValueFrom(
      this._configFacade.configState$.pipe(take(1)),
    );
    console.log('And we get here each time too!');

    return { t: 'something' };
  }

But I'm still wondering why it didn't work by rxjs Observables syntax!

Maybe you are subscribing only once. Use Stackblitz to reproduce.

I'm not actually subscribing to it. I just return the Observable... But it should definitely get into the map operator... But it just won't go into the the operator...

I figured it out! It was as easy as ABC! When I was actually using the Transloco Service load method (to eventually call getTranslation method on the Transloco loader service) I had to subscribe to it:
private readonly _langService = inject(TranslocoService);
this._langService
  .load('en')
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe();

Calling the load method alone, won't go to the map operator, as we don't subscribe to it! But async function was working, because await fetches the results first, and then continues...
